# Fastest way to remove inline CSS of an element and all its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to delete all inline CSS from an element and all its children.

Now I do in this way:

```js
$('#element').attr('style', '');
$('#element').find('div').attr('style', '');
$('#element').find('a').attr('style', '');
$('#element').find('span').attr('style', '');
$('#element').find('p').attr('style', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element" style="color:red">
  <div id="childrenA" style="background: red">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline">bla bla</a>
  </div>
  <div id="childrenB" style="width: 100px"></div>
  <span style="height:50px"><p style="overflow:hidden"></p></span>
</div>
```

But that is a lot of code.... Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just:

```
$('#element, #element *').attr('style','');
```

you can achieve alot from css selector, read more about it here

> The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize,
>   [here.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```js
$('#element, #element *').removeAttr('style');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element" style="color:red">
  <div id="childrenA" style="background: red">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline">bla bla</a>
  </div>
  <div id="childrenB" style="width: 100px"></div>
  <span style="height:50px"><p style="overflow:hidden"></p></span>
</div>
```

Literally - find `#element`, and any elements under it, then remove any `style` attributes they might have.

Answer (score 1):

You could just select all the descendant elements using the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) and then use the [`.addBack()` method](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add back the initial element:

```
$('*', '#element').addBack().removeAttr('style');
```

or:

```
$('#element').find('*').addBack().removeAttr('style');
```